# Append columns in csv file by matching the fields with another csv file in bash

Tags: csv, awk

I have 2 csv files. File1 is an existing list of private IP address & its hostname. File2 is a daily report which has 8 columns in which 2 containing the private IP.
I want to compare file2 with with file1 by matching field 4 and field 7 of file2 with field 2 of file1. Then, upon matching, I want to append field 3 and field 6 of file2 according to the matches of field 4 and field 7 with field 2 of file1.

File1.csv

```
PC1,192.168.3.1
PC2,192.168.3.2
PC3,192.168.3.3
```

File2.csv (Has about 50 lines)

```
Port,Type,S_Host,S_IP,Port,D_Host,D_IP,Port
2,tcp,N/A,192.168.3.1,2,N/A,192.168.3.2,8
3,tcp,N/A,192.168.3.2,2,N/A,192.168.3.3,3
```

I need to do a bash script to automate file2.

Desired output:

```
Port,Type,S_Host,S_IP,Port,D_Host,D_IP,Port
2,tcp,PC1,192.168.3.1,2,PC2,192.168.3.2,8
3,tcp,PC2,192.168.3.2,2,PC3,192.168.3.3,3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hint: You can use `join` command.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: added my desired output :)

Comment: Read file1 into an array in `awk` (indexed by IP) then process file2 and lookup the hostname using the IP from fields 4 & 7 and set fields 3 & 6  equal to the resulting hostnames and print the record.

Comment: Hi David, would appreciate if you could show the full script Im new to bash scripting and Im stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume there are no white spaces in the original CSV files.

Comment: You told me above there were no spaces after the comma in your CSV file, but in a comment below, you say there are. So your file is not a CSV (comma separated values) file but a CSSV file: "comma-space separated values". So I will adapt my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input files look like this, i.e. the first version, with spaces after the comma:

File1.csv

```
Host, IP
PC1, 192.168.3.1
PC2, 192.168.3.2
PC3, 192.168.3.3
```

and:

File2.csv

```
Port, Type, S_Host, S_IP, Port, D_Host, D_IP, Port
2, tcp, N/A, 192.168.3.1, 2, N/A, 192.168.3.2, 8
3, tcp, N/A, 192.168.3.2, 2, N/A, 192.168.3.3, 3
```

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = ", "; OFS = ", "}
  (FNR == NR) && (NR > 1) {hh[$2] = $1}
  NR > FNR {
    if (FNR == 1) 
      print; 
    else 
      print $1, $2, hh[$4], $4, $5, hh[$7], $7, $8;
  }
' File1.csv File2.csv
```

This is the ouput I get:

```
Port, Type, S_Host, S_IP, Port, D_Host, D_IP, Port
2, tcp, PC1, 192.168.3.1, 2, PC2, 192.168.3.2, 8
3, tcp, PC2, 192.168.3.2, 2, PC3, 192.168.3.3, 3
```

> Also, if the IP is a public IP, I need to do a whois search instead to get the OrgName

I suggest you to post another question about this second topic. It is like in professional emails: one item = one question.

Comment: I'm only getting empty spaces at the 3rd and 6th column Pierre.

Comment: Somebody upvoted my answer but you say there is an issue about empty spaces. Does it work or not? And if not, what happens exactly? With the input files you gave after removing the blanks, I get the desired output (see my edited answer with the output).

Comment: It's not working. The column 3 and 6 returns empty in the output.

Comment: @scriptdummy: Are there white spaces after the comma in your csv files?

Comment: Yes Pierre there are white spaces after the comma in my csv files

Comment: I will edit your question and add the spaces after every comma in both files, and modify the script according to that.

Comment: It is not a good practice in SO to add another question inside of an already existing question. Please, post a new question asking how to perform a reverse DNS look up in AWK.

Comment: I tried your script again and again. its not working Pierre.

Comment: Try to describe "not working" with more details: input, output, how did you copy/paste the script, are you sure there are no tipos, etc...?

Comment: I only can say that it my script working in my environment with the input files as above.

Comment: In the output, column 3 and column 6 returns empty. I did not copy paste the script but i typed it back exactly the same. Can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I would try to copy/paste the script instead of overwriting it. You will save time and avoid errors. One missing space after the the comma in `BEGIN {FS = ", ";` for example could explain your script is not working.

Comment: copy pasted your script. run it and still the same problem. Column 3 and 6 returns empty in the output.

Comment: OK. Lets do the contrary now: paste your input files File1.csv and File2.csv into your question above. If the problem is not in the code, it is in the input files.

Comment: I edited the existing file1 and file2. I removed the spaces. Everything else is the same. So, if i removed the empty spaces, it should be {FS = ",";}. I run it again and i get the same error.

Comment: I think a part of the problem is that you always do something different than what we are suggesting you to do. I ask you for example to post the files with spaces (as I understood these are in reality) and you paste the files without spaces, adapting the script. If you constantly change the environment, I hardly understand how you ever will get a solution. In my environment, it works in both cases: with spaces after the comma and without. On which platform are you working?

Comment: Is it possible that instead of using a text editor for coding, you are using a wordprocessor changing the double quotes of `"some stuff"` into `“some stuff”`?

Comment: I'm working on VirtualBox Oracle 6 . I use Vim editor to write my script

Comment: I am eager to know if the file format of VIM is correct. When you edit `File1.csv`, I suggest you to hit ESCAPE and to enter command `:set fileformat` followed by RETURN. You will see a message at the bottom of the screen. Tell me, please if it is `fileformat=unix`.

Comment: If your input files are exactly as described above, I am out of ideas. There will be probably some difference at your side I can't figure out.